# Data Leak issue with moxie manager

Tags: php, tinymce, symfony-2.5, moxiemanager

I am using the moxie manager with tiny-mc to upload files on server.User able to upload the files but one user can able to access the files of other users on server.How can I set the privacy so that user can  only access his own files.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version are you using and what is your configuration in javascript and config.php?